# Ориентация по оси X

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Arial';}

.clearfix:after {visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }

* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;  }



.innerWrapper {
 max-width: 920px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}



h2 {
 font-size: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 100px;
 margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

/* NAV SECTION */

.companyName {
 padding: 6px 17px 5px 10%;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 color: #fff;
 width: 45%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 text-align: left;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

nav {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 55%;
 float: right;
}


header nav ul {
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 border-right: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

header nav ul li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 display: inline;
 width: 25%;
 text-align: center;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

header nav ul li:hover {
 background: none;
    font-style: bold;
}

header nav ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 13px 20px;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Arial', serif;
 font-size: 1rem;
}

header nav ul li a:focus {
 outline: none;
}

/* HEAD SECTION */

header {
 background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/15/02/22/fantasy-2750995_960_720.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

.hero {
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 1px 0 2px #595859;
}

.hero h1 {
 font-size: 5.5rem;
 margin:0;
 padding-top: 200px;
 font-family: 'Arial', serif;
 color: #fff;
}

.hero h3 {
 padding-bottom: 10.4em;
 font-family: 'Arial', serif;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin: 0;
}

/* SECTION */

.intro {
    background: url(/img/intro.jpg) 50%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 18%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: none;
    background-color: #5c564e;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.intro .content h1 {
    background: rgb(158, 20, 128);
    width: 880px;
}


.intro:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background-color: #cc3ab9;
}

.intro {
    height: 30vh;
}


  
.content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* SECTION2 */

.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}

.section {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    color: #fff;
    transition: flex .4s ease;
    position: relative;
}

.section .overlay {
    background-color: rgba(80, 79, 79, 0.075);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: background-color .8s ease;
}

.section .content {
    z-index: 2;
}
.section:hover {
    flex: 2;
}

.section:hover .overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.342);
}

#history {
    background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/08/01/03/old-letters-1082299_960_720.jpg) 30% 15%;
}

#statistic {
    background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/27/21/42/stock-1863880_960_720.jpg) 21% 45%;
}

@media (max-width:900px) {
  .companyName {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4% 4%;
  }
  
 .mainNav {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  header nav ul {
    border: none;
  }
  
  header nav ul li a {
    padding: 25px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <div class="navWrapper" id="home">
      <div class=" clearfix">
        <h2 class="companyName">DS</h2>
        <nav class="mainNav clearfix">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#two" class="smoothScroll">two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tree" class="smoothScroll">tree</a></li>
            <li><a href="#four" class="smoothScroll">four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section class="hero">
      <div class="innerWrapper">
        <h1>hjhdjhddjhdkjdsf</h1>
        <h3>fsdfsdf dfsdf</h3>
      </div>
    </section>
  </header>

  <section class="intro">  
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est, ratione!</h1>
   </div>
  </section>
<!-- section2 -->
  <div class="container">
    <div id="history" class="section">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>История</h1>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="overlay"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="statistic" class="section">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Статистика</h1>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="overlay"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/rediguana/pen/MPzxMB
помогите убрать ориентацию по оси X, какой то элемент выходит за экран я никак не могу понять как это фиксануть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае нужно добавить это:

```
h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: это уберет проблему h1 на мобильной версии, я видел это, но на полной странице проблема останется. Для удобства я приложил код на кодпен

Comment: @kkkkkkkk сотрите `h1` в классе `.intro`